# Database sort on numeric values that are actually strings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below query. In that `field_a` is `String` property and `field_b` is an array of type `Number`. I want an array having property `field_a` and `field_b` with unique combination. Here `field_a` contains numeric value but in string format. So I want to apply natural sort in aggregation pipeline. `$natural` can be used only with such query `db.collection.find().sort( { $natural: 1 } )`

So how can I use natural sort in MongoDB or I need to depend upon JS functions or on lodash/underscore.js ?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": { "_id": { field_a: "$field_a", field_b: "$field_b" } } },
    { $project: { a: "$_id" } },
    {"$group": {"_id": 'a', "res": {"$addToSet": "$_id" }}},
    {"$unwind": "$res"},
    {"$sort": { "res": 1}},
    {"$group": { "_id": null, "res": {"$push": "$res" }}}
])
```

Comment: Who told you that [`$natural`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) would help you here? It's usage has nothing to do with what you are talking about. You are talking about sorting strings like this `[ "5", "50", "6", 60" ]` into a numeric order right? You cannot do that, unless we get fancy and "zero pad" the values.

Comment: @NeilLunn Nobody told but I thought it could work. What do you mean by "_unless we get fancy and "zero pad" the values_" ?

Comment: Your `field_a` contains numeric data as strings much like I listed above, and the problem is that as shown a `"50"` is considers less than `"6"` yes? ( means I actually need you to confirm that ). And what I mean is that depending on your MongoDB server version in use, then you might be able to do something about that to enable a server side sort.

Comment: Yeah if my result data is `[ "5", "50", "6", "60" ]` I need them as `[ "5", "6", "50", "60" ]`

Comment: Okay. Additional question. What is the above aggregation supposed to achieve? Is this all just an exercise to get the unique combination of the two fields, and in sorted order? Just trying to understand the intent since there are so many unnecessary steps being taken. Can you also please confirm your mongodb server version.

Comment: I am using v3.4.2. You are right I need a unique combination of two fields with natural sort by `field_a`.

Answer (score 1):

I short, this is what you want to do here:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "field_a": {
        "$concat": [
          { "$substrCP": [ 
            "0000000000",
            0,
            { "$subtract": [ 10, { "$strLenCP": "$field_a" } ] }
          ]},
          "$field_a"
        ]
      },
      "field_b": "$field_b"
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

---

### Explanation

As a basic concept, the problem you have is that "strings" sort in in a way that does not translate to how numeric sorts work.

As a brief example, these documents use a string value:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928276f84c3559bc2fd458b"), "a" : "5" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928277484c3559bc2fd458c"), "a" : "50" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928277e84c3559bc2fd458d"), "a" : "60" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928278284c3559bc2fd458e"), "a" : "6" }
```

If you try to sort these, then the lexical order applies:

```
> db.list.find().sort({ "a": 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928276f84c3559bc2fd458b"), "a" : "5" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928277484c3559bc2fd458c"), "a" : "50" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928278284c3559bc2fd458e"), "a" : "6" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928277e84c3559bc2fd458d"), "a" : "60" }
```

As strings, this makes sense. Since a `"50"` begins with `"5"` and is therefore less than the `"6"`.

Since the aggregation framework cannot "cast" these as numeric values, then your only option is to present the "strings" in a way in which they will order lexically in the same way as they would with numeric values.

In brief terms we "zero pad" them, which is essentially making the values fixed length strings which are prefixed or "padded" with `0` which makes the "strings" appear to be ordered like they would be numerically:

```
db.list.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "a": {
      "$concat": [
        { "$substrCP": [ 
          "0000000000",
          0,
          { "$subtract": [ 10, { "$strLenCP": "$a" } ] }
        ]},
        "$a"
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "a": 1 } }
])
```

And this will produce a list in order like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928276f84c3559bc2fd458b"), "a" : "0000000005" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928278284c3559bc2fd458e"), "a" : "0000000006" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928277484c3559bc2fd458c"), "a" : "0000000050" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5928277e84c3559bc2fd458d"), "a" : "0000000060" }
```

---

The basic premise here is that you take a "template" string, which is in this example a string of `0` which is 10 characters long. Then we look at the length of the field data to transform using [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) and [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) that length from `10` which is the length of the template string used here.

The difference in length is fed to the [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) operator as the number of characters to take from the template. This output is then fed to [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) in order to make a "string" which like the template is 10 characters long, but starts with zeros and ends in the initial numeric string.

---

In your actual usage, this will end up as part of a composite key. Yet since the transformed key is first in the key order, then simply sorting by `_id` considers this and primarily sorts by values in the first key and then the second.

Comment: Thanks mate your solution is awesome, but is there any way to remove those leading zeroes? I found solutions only using `forEach` loops. Is there any way using query?

Comment: @Xyroid Can you remove the zeroes on the server? No you cannot, because basically that would be "casting to numeric" and if we could do that then we would not be doing this in the first place. In the client, then of course you can. Which is then basically the point of if manipulation is possible in client code then do it there. You really should only be doing things on the server where it matters. Such as doing the "sort" on the server so you can "limit" the response to return.